# Determining damped frequency and damping ratio from time domain data

Tags: control-engineering, aerospace-engineering

I have some time domain data which are responses of an aircraft to various inputs (example: time vs. bank angle for lateral stick pulse input). I need to compute the effective damping ratio and damped frequency of these "signals".

I considered several options but none worked as well as I hoped.

- Computing instantaneous frequency and damping ratio using Hilbert transform: This does not give single frequency and damping values. Also, I get negative values sometimes.
- Finding approximate second order system and using its parameters: Works for some test cases but I have test cases where the signal can not be represented well with second order system.
- Simply detecting the peaks (minima/maxima) in the signal and using them: In some test cases I don't have oscillations, i.e. no peaks. Besides I am not sure how to use the peaks to compute the damping ratio.

Is there any robust method to do this type of analysis?